# What is the correct way to remove Entity Framework 4.3 from your project?

Tags: entity-framework-4

I have a solution that uses EF Code First. I recently upgraded all my projects to [EF](http://nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework) 4.3 (using NuGet).  However, afterwards I discovered that another package ([EFHooks](http://nuget.org/packages/EFHooks)) doesn't work with that version.

So I decided to roll back the version to 4.1.10715.0 which is the latest version that I could get to work with EFHooks.

When I compile the application, everything compiles fine. I can run all my tests and they pass (unit tests, integration tests, database tests, etc.). However, when I run the web site (mvc 3), it gives me a runtime error stating

> Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework' or one of its
>   dependencies. ... Version=4.3.0.0 etc etc

I've checked all my packages.config, and my web.config. I've checked all the referenced dlls versions. Everything is lined up with 4.1.

I can't find anywhere in my solution that uses anything for 4.3, yet the site is trying to find it because of something.

Is there something in my rollback that I missed?

Comment: How did you perform rollback? Btw. did you try to change assembly binding and retarget 4.1.10715.0 to 4.3?

Comment: I went through each project and did a Uninstall-Package command through the PM console. I'll try re-targeting back to 4.3 and see if it starts the web site, but that wouldn't really fix my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the **real error** was that I didn't have my DBContext wired up to my IoC container. In this case, Ninject.

So when the DBContext was requested the IoC container errored out, because it didn't have one wired up to give to the application.

I do not understand why it gave me the error that it did, but for anyone going through the same steps, I hope this might prove useful if you find yourself in the same place that I did.

So, all the code I needed to add was basically just the following:

```
Bind<ICustomSession>().To<EFDBContext>().InRequestScope();
```

Answer (score 1):

Points to check:

1. Verify that `web.config` binds to version you want
2. Verify `\bin` folder contains assemblies of the correct version
3. Perform `iisreset` and delete temporay files from `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files`
4. Try [redirecting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wd6ex19.aspx) assemblies to the version you want

Comment: Good suggestions KMoraz. Unfortunately the error I was getting really didn't have anything to do with my actual problem.